# How change appium capabilities dynamically using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cucumber, appium, webdriver-io

I use webdriverio and cucumber.
I want change appium capabilities(language and locale) in running test.

I have

```
    config.capabilities = [
    {
        platformName: 'Android',
        maxInstances: 1,
        port: 4723,
        path: '/wd/hub',
        'appium:deviceName': 'OnePlus',
        'appium:udid': 'b22a8021',
        'appium:language': 'ru',   
        'appium:locale': 'RU',       
        'appium:platformVersion': '11',
        'appium:orientation': 'PORTRAIT',
        'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
        'appium:app': './apps/demo.apk'',
        'appium:fullReset': true,
        'appium:newCommandTimeout': 240,
        'appium:enableWebviewDetailsCollection': true
    },
];
```

What should I do in test so that the language and locale change to en? This isn't works

```
Given(/^Device lang en$/, () => {
driver.capabilities.desired.language = 'en';
driver.capabilities.desired.locale = 'EN';
});
```

and **setCapability** isn't works

I would be grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

just had the same problem today. This is how I've deal with that:

```
// @ts-ignore
driver.requestedCapabilities['appium:language'] = language;
// @ts-ignore
driver.requestedCapabilities['appium:locale'] = locale;
await driver.reloadSession();
```